# Java. Как прочитать ответ от сервера

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, потоки-данных

Посылаю запрос на сервер с помощью Socket Ouptut Stream. Теперь хочу получить ответ. Попытался считывать его через тот же Socket, пользуясь Input Stream, но заметил что данные получаются перемешанными, много раз повторяющимися. Я  так понимаю это из-за особенностей работы TCP (при неудачной отправке пакета отправляем повторно). Но вот тут то и вопрос как максимально просто и быстро прочитать ответ с сервера?

Код (да, я тупо не знаю как определить признак окончания потока. Если ставить проверять is.read на количество прочитанного, всё замирает на неопределенное время, видимо в ожидании следующей порции данных):

```
        is = socket.getInputStream();
        String r;

        do {
            is.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            r = new String(buffer);
            sBuilder.append(r);
        } while (r.indexOf("</response>") < 0);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это не "особенности работы TCP", а ваша недоработка, TCP как раз гарантирует, что вы получите то, что было отправлено в том порядке, в каком было отправлено, или увидите ошибку. Вы просите заполнить буфер байтами из потока, записав их с 0 до `BUFFER_SIZE`. Дальше вы из буфера создаете строку, проверяете, нет ли в ней нужной подстроки, и все повторяете. Поскольку нет гарантии, что `read` заполнит весь массив, там остаются данные с предыдущего чтения, в результате в строке получается мешанина из новых данных, не перезаписанных старых данных и незаполненного хвост буфера. Все это дописывается в `StringBuilder` каждый раз.

Проще всего, когда сервер закроет соединение по окончании передачи, тогда не нужно следить за данными, поток закончится, и `InputStream.read` вернет `-1`:

```
try ( Socket socket = new Socket( InetAddress.getByName( "httpbin.org" ), 80 ) ) {
    // типа гет-запрос
    socket.getOutputStream().write( ("GET /ip HTTP/1.0\n"
            + "Host: httpbin.org\n"
            + "Accept: text/html\n\n").getBytes( StandardCharsets.US_ASCII ) );
    socket.getOutputStream().flush();

    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    // ByteArrayOutputStream используется, как накопитель байт, чтобы
    //   потом превратить в строку все полученные данные.
    //   преобразовывать часть потока в строку опасно, т.к.
    //   если данные идут в многобайтной кодировке, один символ может
    //   быть разрезан между чтениями
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // InputStream.read( byte[] ) возвращает количество прочитанных байт
    //   и -1, если поток кончился (сервер закрыл соединение)
    for ( int received; (received = is.read( buffer )) != -1; ) {
        // записываем прочитанное из потока, от 0 до количества считанных
        baos.write( buffer, 0, received );
    }

    // преобразуем в строку ( кодировку желательно указывать )
    String reply = baos.toString( "UTF-8" );
    // можно так, но toByteArray() создает копию массива, а я у мамы оптимизатор
    //String reply = new String( baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );

    System.out.println( reply );
}
```

Если сервер соединение не закрывает (допустим у нас чат и сервер шлет сообщения), то придется смотреть на данные, и выделять отдельные сообщения согласно протоколу. Примитивно можно попробовать как-то так:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
// InputStreamReader преобразует поток байт в поток символов, в нужной кодировке
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
// буфер теперь из char
char[] buffer = new char[8192];

// собирать будем в StringBuilder
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int received;

String reply = null;
// чтение выглядит точно так же, как с InputStream
while ( (received = reader.read( buffer )) != -1 ) {
    // дописываем в StringBuilder
    builder.append( buffer, 0, received );

    // ищем тег
    int tail = builder.indexOf( "</response>" );
    if ( tail >= 0 ) {
        int len = tail + "</response>".length();
        // вынимаем из буфера строку
        reply = builder.substring(0, len );
        // оставляем в буфере хвост для следующих данных 
        builder.delete( 0, len );
        break;
    }
}

// мы можем и не получить строку, если поток кончился раньше
if ( reply != null ) {
    System.out.println( reply );
}
```

Если размер сообщения откуда-то заранее известен, можно ориентироваться по нему:

```
int remaining = messageSize;
int received;
while ( remaining > 0 && (received = is.read( buffer )) != -1 ) {
    baos.write( buffer, 0, Math.min( received, remaining ) );
    remaining = remaining - received;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема как раз была в read, я блин не подумал, что читаю я не обязательно по размеру буфера, а записываю в строку весь буфер. Дурацкие примеры из интернета меня сбили с толку.